Types of involutions in simple algebras
Let $A$ be a finite-dimensional simple $K$-algebra with centre $Z$, and so central simple $Z$-algebra. Suppose $A$ has involution whose fixed field is $K_0$. Consider the following four cases:
1-Case $K_0=K=Z$: It is well-known that the involution is of first-type in the central simple $K$-algebra $A$. The involution is either orthogonal or symplectic.
2-Case $K_0 \ne K=Z$: It is well-known that the involution is of second-type in the central simple $K$-algebra $A$. The involution is unitary.
3-Case $K_0=K \ne Z$.
4-Case $K_0 \ne K \ne Z$.
Now, my question is whether the theory of involution in Cases 3 and 4 is a generalization or a refinement of the theory of involution in central simple algebras? or is the theory for Cases 3 and 4 fully covered by Case 2?
